# How to do cross field validation with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am seeing a lot of help writing custom jQuery validation for any type of field on my page, but how would I write a custom validation method that takes values from multiple fields into account (cross-filed validation)? I **think** I'm supposed to do `$.validator.addMethod` to add my custom method and then add a rule to the validator object (instead of to a specific field), but I am having trouble with the syntax. Can anyone help?

For example,

I have two fields: date and time. My form is valid only if:

1. Both are filled
2. The date is not a sunday
3. The time is between 6am and 6pm

Comment: Can you give an example? What kind of validation do you want to perform?

Comment: I have two fields: date and time. My form is valid only if: a) both are filled b) the date is not a sunday c) the time is between 6am and 6pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need some custom rules here, but each validation method doesn't need to take multiple fields into account. Seems to me, you need three different rules: required applied to both fields (already built in) and then a custom rule for the time rule (6AM - 6PM) and the day rule (can't be a Sunday):

```
$.validator.addMethod("notsunday", function (value, element) {
    var date = Date.parse(value);
    return this.optional(element) || (date && date.getDay() !== 0);
});

$.validator.addMethod("businesshours", function (value, element) {
    var time = Date.parse(value);
    return this.optional(element) ||
        (time && (time.getHours() >= 6 && time.getHours() <= 18));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").validate({
        rules: {
            date: {
                required: true,
                notsunday: true
            },
            time: {
                required: true,
                businesshours: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            date: {
                notsunday: "Can't be a Sunday!"
            },
            time : {
                businesshours: "Must be between 6AM and 6PM"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/7KFgn/

**Note** that the example uses [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) to make parsing the dates easier.

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever received on SO. If I could give you two upvotes I would. I neglected to mention the important rule being that the resulting date/time (combination of the fields) must be later than now. I can figure out from your example how to do this (by just attaching it to a field) but I wonder if there's such thing as a validation that doesn't "belong" to a field, but rather to the entire form.

Comment: @JeremyFoster: I'll update my answer with an example of combined-field validation